# マイナス投票した後、元の数字に戻す事ができますか？

Tags: サポート, 投票

元の数字を忘れてしまいました。
マイナス投票した後、プラス投票には、できる?
元2→マイナス投票→1→プラス投票→3→マイナス投票→1
①これで、正しいですか？

②プラス投票でなく、賛成投票(upvote)という表現が正しいですか？

Comment: ご質問の意図がよく分かりませんでした。マイナス投票を取り消したいという意味でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 元の数字を忘れてしまいました。
> マイナス投票した後、プラス投票には、できる?
> 元2→マイナス投票→1→プラス投票→3→マイナス投票→1
> **①これで、正しいですか？**

各個人が操作できるのは、その人自身の投票だけです。

貴方が記事にマイナス投票をした際には、▼が灰色からオレンジ(マイナスはしたことがないのでプラスの情報ですが)/(METAでは黒)になっているはずです(そしてマウスカーソルをかざして表示されるツールチップに`(元に戻すにはもう一度クリック)`と追加表示されている)が、それをもう一度クリックすれば、自分自身のマイナス投票だけを取り消せます。

投票数の数字は他の人の投票も含めた総数であり、それを誰か個人が意図的に変更することはできません。

---

> **②プラス投票でなく、賛成投票(upvote)という表現が正しいですか？**

ヘルプ内の記述は両方あるようなので、どちらでも良いでしょう。
あるいは統一した方が良いという意見なのかもしれませんが。

Answer (score 4):

kunif さんの回答に補足しておくと、投票直後の取り消しは **5分以内** であれば可能です。

5分を経過するとあなたの投票はいったんロックされ、対象の投稿が編集されるまで投票の見直しもできなくなります。(いたずら、嫌がらせ目的でのマイナス票を防ぐため)

**参考:**
[What's the purpose of locking a vote down until the next edit? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251232)